# Defining objects - clean method Java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in programming and I got really big problem about defining objects in method what makes me confused.

When I'm creating a method I need to redefine object defined in OnCreate method. Is there easier way to define object in method without copying that to every method? Example of my code down... Please don't laugh loud and help me... :D

```
private void leafsSwitchClicked() {

        Global.selectedTradeItem = 1;

        ImageView selectedItemImage = findViewById(R.id.selectedItemImage);
        selectedItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.leafs_icon_shop);

        TextView todayPriceTextDM = findViewById(R.id.todayPriceTextDM);
        TextView lastPriceTextDM = findViewById(R.id.lastPriceTextDM);
        TextView ownedItemsTextDM = findViewById(R.id.ownedItemsTextDM);

        todayPriceTextDM.setText("" + Global.leafsPrice + " $");
        lastPriceTextDM.setText("" + Global.lastLeafsPrice + " $");
        ownedItemsTextDM.setText("" + Global.ownedLeafsQty);

        LinearLayout leafsSwitch = findViewById(R.id.leafsSwitch);
        leafsSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon);
        LinearLayout pillsSwitch = findViewById(R.id.pillsSwitch);
        pillsSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout syringeSwitch = findViewById(R.id.syringeSwitch);
        syringeSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout powderSwitch = findViewById(R.id.powderSwitch);
        powderSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout fungusSwitch = findViewById(R.id.fungusSwitch);
        fungusSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout crystalSwitch = findViewById(R.id.crystalSwitch);
        crystalSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);

        ImageView leafsBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.leafsBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView pillsBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.pillsBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView syringeBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.syringeBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView powderBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.powderBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView fungusBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.fungusBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView crystalBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.crystalBottomBarIcon);

        leafsBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0)));
        pillsBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        syringeBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        powderBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        fungusBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        crystalBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));

        TextView quantityTextDM = findViewById(R.id.quantityTextDM);
        TextView totalTextDM = findViewById(R.id.totalTextDM);
        SeekBar seekBarDM = findViewById(R.id.seekBarDM);

        if (Global.sellingMode == 1) {
            seekBarDM.setMax(Global.ownedLeafsQty);
            seekBarDM.setProgress(Global.ownedLeafsQty);
            quantityTextDM.setText("" + Global.ownedLeafsQty);
            totalTextDM.setText(Global.ownedLeafsQty * Global.leafsPrice + " $");
        }

    }

    private void pillsSwitchClicked() {

        Global.selectedTradeItem = 2;

        TextView todayPriceTextDM = findViewById(R.id.todayPriceTextDM);
        TextView lastPriceTextDM = findViewById(R.id.lastPriceTextDM);
        TextView ownedItemsTextDM = findViewById(R.id.ownedItemsTextDM);

        todayPriceTextDM.setText("" + Global.pillsPrice + " $");
        lastPriceTextDM.setText("" + Global.lastPillsPrice + " $");
        ownedItemsTextDM.setText("" + Global.ownedPillsQty);

        ImageView selectedItemImage = findViewById(R.id.selectedItemImage);
        selectedItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pills_icon_shop);

        LinearLayout leafsSwitch = findViewById(R.id.leafsSwitch);
        leafsSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout pillsSwitch = findViewById(R.id.pillsSwitch);
        pillsSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon);
        LinearLayout syringeSwitch = findViewById(R.id.syringeSwitch);
        syringeSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout powderSwitch = findViewById(R.id.powderSwitch);
        powderSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout fungusSwitch = findViewById(R.id.fungusSwitch);
        fungusSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);
        LinearLayout crystalSwitch = findViewById(R.id.crystalSwitch);
        crystalSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon_gray);

        ImageView leafsBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.leafsBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView pillsBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.pillsBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView syringeBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.syringeBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView powderBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.powderBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView fungusBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.fungusBottomBarIcon);
        ImageView crystalBottomBarIcon = findViewById(R.id.crystalBottomBarIcon);

        leafsBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        pillsBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0)));
        syringeBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        powderBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        fungusBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));
        crystalBottomBarIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 0)));

        TextView quantityTextDM = findViewById(R.id.quantityTextDM);
        TextView totalTextDM = findViewById(R.id.totalTextDM);
        SeekBar seekBarDM = findViewById(R.id.seekBarDM);

        if (Global.sellingMode == 1) {
            seekBarDM.setMax(Global.ownedPillsQty);
            seekBarDM.setProgress(Global.ownedPillsQty);
            quantityTextDM.setText("" + Global.ownedPillsQty);
            totalTextDM.setText(Global.ownedPillsQty * Global.pillsPrice + " $");
        }

        if (Global.buyingMode == 1) {
            int step = 1;
            double numbermin = (double) Global.pillsPrice;
            double numbermax = (double) Global.moneyQty;
            double maxi = (double) (numbermax / numbermin);
            int max = (int) maxi;
            int min = 0;
            seekBarDM.setMax((max - min) / step);
            seekBarDM.setProgress(max);
            quantityTextDM.setText("" + max);
            totalTextDM.setText(max * Global.pillsPrice + " $");
        }

    }
```

This is something what I want (but this won't work correctly)... Or maybe is a trick to put Methods in other class file like Methods.java and implementing that to other fil without errors...?

```
public class Darkmarket extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.darkmarket);

        defineLL();

        setLL();

    }


    private void defineLL() {
        LinearLayout leafsSwitch = findViewById(R.id.leafsSwitch);
        LinearLayout pillsSwitch = findViewById(R.id.pillsSwitch);
        LinearLayout syringeSwitch = findViewById(R.id.syringeSwitch);
        LinearLayout powderSwitch = findViewById(R.id.powderSwitch);
        LinearLayout fungusSwitch = findViewById(R.id.fungusSwitch);
        LinearLayout crystalSwitch = findViewById(R.id.crystalSwitch);
    }

    private void setLL() {
        leafsSwitch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shop_icon);
    }

    private void backButtonClicked() {
        Intent goBack = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(goBack);
    }
}
```

Almost Everyting from 2 days...

Answer (score 0):

I asked ChatGPT but he told me answer like that:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

}

private void otherMethod() {

    button.setText("New text");
}
```

}

Why this don't work in my project in Android studio??? I imported a Button class to project but outside OnCreate() button isn't recognized...

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather should be an edit to the question.